# Account Contact Relationship in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm

How do I apply a contact to an account?

So I have an account and a contact

Account acc = new Account{Name="Ab..",};

Contact co = new Contact{Name="John", ..};

And then

```
CreateOneToManyRequest createOneToManyRelationshipRequest =
                        new CreateOneToManyRequest
{
   OneToManyRelationship = new OneToManyRelationshipMetadata
   {
       //What should I put here?
   },
   Lookup = new LookupAttributeMetadata
   {
       //And here?
   }
};
CreateOneToManyResponse createOneToManyRelationshipResponse =
                        (CreateOneToManyResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(
                        createOneToManyRelationshipRequest);
```

Are I on the right track? or is there some other way of connecting contacts to accounts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateOneToManyRequest` is used to create a new relationship between entities (not records), i.e. change the database schema. I take it this is not what you want to do.

To attach a specific contact record to an account, set its `parentcustomerid` property. Thîs will be an `EntityReference` or `Lookup` or the like and take the ID and type ("account") of the 1 side of that 1:n relationship.

Comment: Thanks, That worked out great, it where exactly what I where trying to do.